# How to get build number from jenkins to display in vscode extensions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

We are devloping one vscode plugin and we are using jenkins to build the code after each commit.
When devloper commit something in jenkins it builds a `.vsix` file. Problem is when tester downloads that file all builds `.vsix` file name is the same. We are not able to trace which build we are using. Is there any way using build number or unique number can we trace the build in jenkins?

How to trace which build we are using for testing, is there any way to trace which build(.vsix) file we downloaded from jenkins? How can we trace it in vscode extension development?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in general you can always use the fingerprinting in Jenkins to trace where your artifact was created. But I would recommend to include the build number in your artifact name. A short script you can run within your pipeline after building could be used to rename your file to `project-42.vsix` - if this is your build 42.

**As Pipeline:**

```
def sourceFile = "release-pipeline/project/dist/project.vsix"

if (fileExists(file: sourceFile)) {
   def newFile = "release-pipeline/project/dist/project-${BUILD-ID}.vsix"
   writeFile(file: newFile, encoding: "UTF-8", text: readFile(file: sourceFile, encoding: "UTF-8"))
}
```

**As Freestyle job with a shell script**

```
mv project.vsix project-${BUILD-ID}.vsix
```

Comment: Is this above code need to add it in build section.

Comment: We created job as free style project. can u guide where i need to write this logic.

Comment: you can also include somethins similar in a freestyle job, I will update my answer